# print all lines of a file which contain a specific string

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to search and a log file for specific informations which are contained in the file and get the whole line printed out
for example line 32 in a .log file is:

```
2019-08-07 15:21:09.783             'lineid' -> 'DEU.DTAG.NBGNE00111'
```

I want every line printed out that includes the word lineid.
If someone could help me with my problem I would very appreciate it.
thanks

I am quite new to ruby and regex so I tried by searching something from the internet.

```
File.open("/Users/filip/Documents/Testcases/NG-ART_TC1054921_MKS+Results1/1054921_1042510_2242_TID-2123/TC1042510-TID2123-sequencer.log", "r") do |file|

  for line in file.readlines().include? "lineid"
   puts line
  end
end
```

what I am getting back is only

```
/Users/filip/Documents/cucumber/features/features/step_definitions/lineid.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end
```

Comment: When you just want to print lines of a log file containing the string `lineid` then I would suggest using `grep 'lineid' /Users/filip/Documents/Testcases/NG-...log` in a shell which is certainly much faster than doing this in Ruby.

Comment: @spickermann, good (and educational) suggestion, but I question "much faster" since virtually all the time is spent displaying strings. Moreover, the relevant time is how fast  Greta can read the text displayed on her console.

Comment: Thanks yes, I tried this but I want to use it in a bigger program later on.

Comment: Filip, I think you misunderstood @spickermann's point. You can construct a method `def show_lines(fname, str); \`grep #{str} #{fname}\`; end`. The backticks cause the method to shell out invoke `grep` to print the desired lines.

Comment: [C'mon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/c'mon), do you really need a filename that is as long as a football field for an example?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, of course not, sorry for that. I tried running your suggestion with 

    `def show_lines(fname, str)
       fname= "/file/path.log"
      str = 'lineid'
   ``grep #{str} #{fname}``
end`

But ended up with an empty response. Sorry for my bad understanding of the topic, but am I missing something?

Comment: In order to show the backticks (`\``) in my comment I had to escape them (as I did with the one in this sentence). If you copy my method definition without unescaping the backticks it will not work. Moreover, `fname` is an argument; you can't write `fname = ..` within the method. You need to execute `show_lines("/file..", "lineid")`.  I tested before posting, incidentally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruby is recommended to use `each` to iterate, you don't usually use `for` loops.
You could try this:

```
File.foreach("/Users/filip/Documents/Testcases/NG-ART_TC1054921_MKS+Results1/1054921_1042510_2242_TID-2123/TC1042510-TID2123-sequencer.log").each do |line|
  puts line if line.include?('lineid')
end
```

This will execute the given block for each line in the file without slurping the entire file into memory.

See: [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach)

Making your example work would look like:

```
File.open("/Users/filip/Documents/Testcases/NG-ART_TC1054921_MKS+Results1/1054921_1042510_2242_TID-2123/TC1042510-TID2123-sequencer.log", "r") do |file|

  file.readlines().each do |line|
    puts line if line.include?("erc")
  end
end
```

Comment: @Filip `.match?('lineid')` should be `include? "lineid"` because the `lineid` is a literal string pattern, it has no regex constructs.